# Web Api routing limitations?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, routes

Say I have this 2 actions in my Api Controller :

```
    [HttpGet]
    public Product ProductById(int id)
    {
      ...
        return item;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string ProductByString(string st)
    {
        return "String Result";
    }
```

I also have these 2 routes :

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi",
                "api/{controller}/{id}",
                new
                {
                        id = RouteParameter.Optional
                });

  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi2", "api/{controller}/{st}");
```

Running `http://mysite:9000/api/products/1` will work.

It will catch the **first** route  because there's a match.

if I wanted the STRING action version I must do :

`http://mysite:9000/api/products/?st=blabla` this will be using **ALSO** the first route. ( query string is not negotiation to match a route).

If I swap the routes , only the *DefaultApi2* route  is hit. ( I *do* understand why it is happening).

So my conclusion is that I will never be able to do **both**:

`http://mysite:9000/api/products/1`

**And**

`http://mysite:9000/api/products/Guitar`

In other words - the second route will *never* be a match.

**Question**

Besides

- mentioning the `{action}` name  in the route (not recommended ,web Api conventions)
- using route attribute ( I dont use webApi 2)

What is the right way of solving this issue ? I can see how it can be complicated ( *I 'll have to remember : only the int ID has the `x/y/id` thing , for others I must use querystring etc etc.... I can get lost easily - in a big application)*

Comment: Default web API provides only one method for form-method. Why don't you check inside your api what you are getting?

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ hOw it relates ? web api first match a route  , then finds a controller , then ( according to method)  - select all by prefeix or ATTR , then do match by parameters. I dont see how your comments relates....( or am I missing your point?)

Comment: Did you mean this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620142/web-api-multiple-get-with-same-signature-routing.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Close but not the same. in his answer he added another level of routing. I have no other level. in the same level I want to use Int / String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it can be fixed with three routes:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi",
               "api/{controller}/{id}",
               contraint: new { id = @"\d+" }
               );
// only matches numeric id's

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi2", "api/{controller}/{st}");
// only matches having a parameter, no matter what data type

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi3",
               "api/{controller}/{id}",
               new
               {
                       id = RouteParameter.Optional
               });
// matches the empty id
```

Comment: Yup , I thought about the constraints :-) this is the right direction I believe.

Comment: (deleted the comment) - route #3 is needed when  `api/products/` to supply all. so you're right

Comment: This whole hierarchy can easily go wrong. how would you do in a large app ? I'm simulating a scenario where I have many many routes , and I need to add another route - I think i'll have to go through one by one to see where it doesn't scre* up things....am I right ? is that the way I should work?

Comment: I guess you need more advanced routing for that. I am not using WebAPI yet, just MVC and I just have a custom route name per action (based on a generic approach though). I think there is no nice solution for this without attribute routing.

Comment: Can you elaborate with 3 difference samples for _custom route name per action_ ? ( oh....are you mentioning action in the route ? )

Comment: p.s. can  webapi2  run in vs2010 ? I didnt find information about that

Comment: Yes. I hate to do it. But it is the safest way without breaking the rest.

Comment: I don't know about that. As said, I am not that familiar with WebAPI.