# Why do I require the route attribute?

Tags: c#, inheritance, webapi

I experience a conflict issue while routing, still learning a lot and trying to understand what is happening. I can solve it but I want to really understand what is happening.

I have a base API Controller with generic actions. In the derived API I either override the action or introduce actions with different non conflicting signatures.

In this case - despite both actions have totally different signatures - the routing tells me "Multiple actions were found that match the request" when I try to do a POST.

I do not get this if a) I disable/comment the POST action in the base API controller or b) If I apply a route attribute on the derived action.

I just don't understand why this is needed in the first place. Signatures do not match, and when I post the "dynamic" as an argument it doesn't resemble the generic type expected in the base action. Additionally I am not calling /api/BaseConnection but /api/Connection which adds to the confusion.

```
 public class BaseConnectionController<T> : ApiController where T : Connection
 {
    public async virtual Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string id)
    {
        return Ok(id);
    }
                
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual void Post(T model){} // mitigate issue by removing this action from the base
}
    
public class ConnectionController : BaseConnectionController<Connection>
{
    public async override Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string connectionType){}
   
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Connection")] // mitigate issue with a route attribute
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody] dynamic value){}
}
```

Comment: `model` can both be `T` or `dynamic` type. How does the program know, which endpoint to call, when your parameter fits into both signatures?

Comment: Ah, ofcourse. Unfortunately, because the signatures do not match I am unable to 'hard' override the base action in the derived API. Is there a smarter way of mitigating this besides adding route attributes?

Comment: Maybe you can use something like this? I haven't really ever had the need for anything else than the route attribute. Hope you can use it or someone else sees your post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620142/web-api-multiple-get-with-same-signature-routing, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api